# Cannot find module './message.model'

Tags: angular, api

I'm creating my web application via angular, which I use the API to be able to connect to a nodeJS server, but I have this error message and I do not know what to do

> Cannot find module './message.model'.

app.component.ts
`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Message } from './message.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user = <Message> { id : 1, text : 'Hello'};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  callServer(port) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // ports:
    // :3000 - to call nodejs server
    // :3001 - to call aspnet core server
    this.http.post<Message>(`http://127.0.0.1:${port}/ping`, JSON.stringify(this.user), {
      headers: headers
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}`
```

Comment: Its not able to find message.modal file ... it should be placed in same directory

Comment: Make sure you have imported the 'Message' component correctly from the directory

Comment: Please post your directory structure

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an issue with your `message.model` you have to way to solve this issue

(1) Placed your `message.model` in the same directory 
(2) Change path in `import { Message } from './message.model';` according to your `message.model` path.